# Why are breakpoints never working in nextjs class?

Tags: debugging, next.js, breakpoints

i've followed the nextjs debug guide that was in the doc https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging

breakpoint do work with functionnal components, but never work inside class.
for example in this code

```js
import React from 'react'

class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            number: 1
        }
        this.handeClick = this.handeClick.bind(this)
    }

    handeClick() {
        // breakpoint here
         debugger;
        this.setState({number: this.state.number + 1})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handeClick}>{'Click me!' + this.state.number}</button>
                <Test></Test>
            </div>
        )  
    }
    
}

export default Index
```

the breakpoint simply won't be triggered, any idea why ?
i'm sory if that has already been asked before

Answer (score 0):

You first paint is done on node server. so you need to pass `--inspect` flag to debug the app.
Refer: [nextjs debugging](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging), [nodejs debugging](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)

Comment: i'm using the command `cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev`

Comment: connect to chrome dev tools or vs code debugger. You should be able to debug now.

Comment: also the breakpoints still work with functionnal components

Comment: my problem is that the breakpoints don't work with the class

Answer (score 0):

Ok i'm dumb, vscode only breakpoints server side node breakpoint, not client side, for that i need to use Firefox !